# Is there a flashdrive with embedded RAID 1?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, raid

I need to store some extremely sensitive data on a thumbdrive, and I can't make 2 copies. So if that drive fails, it's a big problem. Have you ever heard of a thumbdrive which is split in 2 and offers RAID 1 mirroring? Or anything that can make the drive redundant?

Thanks

Comment: why a thumbdrive specifically?

Comment: Why can't you make two copies? Because RAID 1 will create two copies of the fie.

Comment: This device will be used by someone who will need to rely on the files for a very long time without possibility of backing them up or of getting a fresh copy. It's complicated, and not really relevant...

Comment: Thumbdrives are not reliable long term storage.

Answer (score 3):

It's pointless to have RAID 1 on a single drive, since if that drive fails you will usually lose access to all copies. Better to have multiple separate drives and then create a RAID 1 volume across them.

Comment: more specifically if the USB interface fails

Comment: I annoys me that you cant edit a comment after some amount of time.  The USB interface is still a single point of failure.  You can have complete redundancy with the RAIDed flash media, but if the USB interface breaks, then you have nothing

Comment: You *COULD* make system that avoided this problem.  Make a "thumb drive" with 0gb on board but two Micro-SD slots.  It would waddle and quack and deliver RAID 1.

Comment: Google shows devices that do just this in 1.8" and 2.5" form factor with a SATA interface and a RAID0 in CF form factor but I can't find what you're after.

Comment: Ideally it would be something like 2 microSD cards enclosed in a USB stick. If the USB fails, you can still extract the cards... Doesn't seem too crazy for 2013!